# lambda function not working in multi-process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use lambda function for multiple arguments in multi-process. However, it is not working properly. There is no run-time error but the CPU is not working on python according to activity monitor. However, `repeat` function is working normally. My code is shown below:

```
def testfun(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    for i in range(100000000):
        pass
    return a+b+c+d+e+f

def multi_process_tfem(a, b, ksis, w, wn, k):
    args = ((a, b, ksi, w, wn, k) for ksi in ksis)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:    
        #results = executor.map(testfun, repeat(a), repeat(b), ksis, repeat(w), repeat(wn), repeat(k)) # working
        results = executor.map(lambda args: testfun(*args), args) # not working
    rho = np.array(list(results))
    return rho
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In module [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) you could use [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) instead of `map` with `lambda`. But it seems `concurrent` doesn't have it. But when you try to use `lambda` in `multiprocessing` then it shows that it can't pickle `lambda` function to send it to process - and it can be also problem in `concurrent` but it doesn't display it.

---

You could get it as one argument and unpack in function

```
def testfun(args):
    a,b,c,d,e,f = args    
    return a+b+c+d+e+f
```

Or you would have to define it as normal function

```
def unpack_testfun(args):
    return testfun(*args)
```

and use it instead of `testfun`

```
executor.map(unpack_testfun, args)
```

---

Example code

```
import concurrent.futures

def testfun1(args):
    a,b,c,d,e,f = args    
    return a+b+c+d+e+f

def multi_process_tfem1(a, b, ksis, w, wn, k):
    args = ((a, b, ksi, w, wn, k) for ksi in ksis)

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:    
        results = executor.map(testfun1, args) 
    return list(results)

print(multi_process_tfem1(1,1,[1,2,3],1,1,1))

# ---

def testfun2(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    return a+b+c+d+e+f

def unpack(args):
    return testfun2(*args)

def multi_process_tfem2(a, b, ksis, w, wn, k):
    args = ((a, b, ksi, w, wn, k) for ksi in ksis)

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:    
        results = executor.map(unpack, args) 
    return list(results)

print(multi_process_tfem2(1,1,[1,2,3],1,1,1))
```

Comment: Thank you @furas. It's working now but lambda function with *args is the same thing as the unpack function defined outside, right? Do you know why just the latter works?

Comment: as I sad at start `multiprocessing` send functions to processes using `pickle` and it has problem to pickle `lambda` (which creates function without name) and it can be problem also in  `concurrent`

Comment: Another potential solution is `functools.partial`, to wrap the function call w/ any args and kwargs. Not near a computer to test this with concurrent.futures / multiprocessing, though.